# Url and port redirection apache 2

Tags: apache2

My problem is that i configured my dns to redirect two urls towards my server url but one of them must contain the port.
exp

```
     www.xxxx.com---> xxx.fff.fff.ggg 
     www.yyyy.com---->xxx.fff.fff.ggg:8080
```

but since dns don't accept port in the conf how should i configure the apache2 server to redirect the url to url:port?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create name-based virtual host on port 80 (this is routine). In the virtualhost with ServerName www.yyyy.com, redirect all traffic to www.yyyy.com:8080.

```
# Only in 2.2:
NameVirtualHost *:80
<Virtualhost *:80>
 ServerName www.xxxx.com
</virtualhost>
<Virtualhost *:80>
 ServerName www.yyyy.com
 Redirect / http://www.yyyy.com:8080/
</virtualhost>
```